# Какой может быть аналог sleep()?

Tags: php, websocket, сокеты

Суть задачи: при запросе на сервер надо отправить 1 сообщение сразу, еще одно через 10 секунд и потом еще 1 еще через 10 секунд.

Для этого я выбрал функцию `sleep()`, которая все делает как надо. Но при ее использовании долго идет ответ от сервера.

Есть ли другой вариант сделать подобный функционал?

P.S. Для отправки сообщений использую сокеты, функция `stream_socket_client`

Answer (score 0):

Первое что приходит на ум это Cron. Он будет выполнять весь скрипт целиком. На счет реализации (примерно), 
т.к у крона минимальное значение времени 1 минута || 60 сек, придется кидать в слип.И

> `* * * * * /path/to/task
>   * * * * * ( sleep 10 ; /path/to/task )`

Answer (score 0):

Открывает вкладки с периодичностью.

```
   <?php
    $file....= данные или тайм в сек
    $suite="laravel.php?blog2=".$file07.".....     ";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.open("'.$suite.'");</script>';
    ?>

    <?php laravel
    set_time_limit($time+10);
    sleep($time)

    $file = 'people.txt';

    $current = file_get_contents($file);

    $current .= date("H:i:s");
    // Пишем содержимое обратно в файл
    file_put_contents($file, $current);

    ?>
```